# aidl file is not working after moving one file to another package

Tags: android, aidl

I am using aidl in my project . It was working fine, but after moving one java file to another package I can't build my project . 
I am getting the following error .

`Process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Here is the content of my aidl file

```
import com.example.app.models.Conversation;
interface IAppService {
     List<Conversation> fetchConversation();
}
```

After I move my `Conversation` file to some other package, I no longer able to build , although the codebase  refactored to following .

```
import com.example.app.db.Conversation;
interface IAppService {
     List<Conversation> fetchConversation();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have changed the package of your file by moving your **Conversation** in another package.

If you are using AIDL between two application then the AIDL file of both the app should be in the same package Example:

If you have App_A and App_B communicating using AIDL then aidl file should be in the same package in both of the app or else you will get an error as **java.lang.SecurityException**

Comment: This is helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTxX5X3XxHE